# Refresh page at specific time and specific date

Tags: javascript, php, html, refresh

I am using JavaScript code for refresh at specific time.  I want to refresh the page at specific time and date. How can I add the date in this code?

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds, day, month, year) {
    var now = new Date('<?php echo date("d M Y H:i:s")?>');
    var then = new Date('<?php echo date("d M Y H:i:s")?>');
    if (now.getHours() > hours ||
        (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setDay(day);
    then.setMonth(month);
    then.setYear(year);
    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);
    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(true);
        window.location = "load.php";
    }, timeout);
}
refreshAt(13, 12, 2013, 21, 25, 00);
```

Comment: `function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds, day, month, year)` doesn't seem to match `refreshAt(13,12,2013,21,25,00)` very well.

Comment: i changed to refreshAt(22,25,00,13,12,2013); but its not working also

Comment: any one here who can help me?

Comment: Please **DO NOT** post duplicate questions. You have already posted this question a few hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend another approach, without JavaScript (pure HTML):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo getRemainingSecondsToRefresh() ?>">
```

Comment: you are right but how i can handle it. i mean to say i want to refresh at specific date and time? how its work?

Comment: any one here who can help me?

Comment: you'll need to calculate the seconds, subtracting `now` from the `specific date and time`) in the `getRemainingSecondsToRefresh` method.